# Custom URL for Navigation Menu

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community, category-attribute

I am trying to create a module that will allow you can define a custom url for a category.

The navigation menu will **link** to a custom page and have the correct URL listed in the sitemap.

I was able to create the custom attribute for the category and it shows in admin but when I try to extend `"Mage_Catalog_Model_Category"` to overwrite the `"getUrl"` function, but I am not able to access my new custom attribute. See below for code. I just want to use the `"custom_category_url"` (if there is a value) otherwise fallback to the parent getUrl function, but currently `$this->getData('custom_category_url')` is always returning **NULL**.

I assume I need to do something so that the attribute is available at this point but I am not sure how. The full code is available at :

> https://github.com/americanstationery/AmstatCustomUrl

```
<?php
class Amstat_CustomUrl_Model_Category extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Category
{
    /**
    * Get category url
    *
    * @return string
    */
    public function getUrl() {
        $categoryRedirectUrl = $this->getData('custom_category_url');
        if(strlen($categoryRedirectUrl) > 0 && $categoryRedirectUrl != '0'){
            return $categoryRedirectUrl;
        }
        return parent::getUrl();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to gain by doing this? You can change a Category's Display Settings to "Static Block Only" and enter all of the same CMS Page information into that Static Block. Your category would hold the META information and give the same Layout/XML options.

Comment: I am trying to link to a custom page (NOT a CMS page) that was created by another extension that allows for customers to request a free catalog. Also, the current URL is highly ranked in google so changing the URL would not be ideal.

Comment: I can't find it in a standalone version - but Meigee's Categories Enhanced (now bundled with their themes) has the ability to add a URL to any category and directly link to it. I use this for an Affiliate extension which creates it's own pages/urls I needed to navigate to from Menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer in `Vinai Kopp's` CategoryLink extension available [here](https://github.com/Vinai/VinaiKopp_CategoryLink). Just needed to add an observer on `catalog_category_collection_load_before` and add the new attribute to the collection.

```
<?php
class Amstat_CustomUrl_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer { 

    public function catalogCategoryCollectionLoadBefore($observer) {
    /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Collection $collection */
    $collection = $observer->getData('category_collection');
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('custom_category_url');
    }
}
```